# Unable to pass JSESSIONID to frontend domain

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, session-cookies, jsessionid

I have an app which uses Spring Boot as backend and ReactJS as frontend. I have used Linkedin OAuth to authorize the users when login in.

When someone logs in, the `JSESSIONID` cookie is created and stored in backend domain (`http://www.my-backend.com`). To use the API in the frontend I need to store the `JSESSIONID` in frontend (`http://www.my-frontend.com`). Can someone help me to solve this issue?

What I want to achieve: Creating the `JSESSIONID` cookie also in frontend domain.

`Application.yml`

```yaml
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          linkedin:
            client-id: ${CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${CLIENT-SECRET}
            client-authentication-method: post
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "http://my-frontend.com"
            scope: r_liteprofile, r_emailaddress
            client-name: Linkedin
        provider:
          linkedin:
            authorization-uri: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization
            token-uri: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken
            user-info-uri: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,localizedFirstName,localizedLastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))
            user-name-attribute: id
            email-address-uri: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://${DB_URL}/${DB_NAME}?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
    username: ${DB_USER_NAME}
    password: ${DB_USER_PASSWORD}
  jmx:
    unique-names: true
```

`SecurityConfig.java`

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf()
      .disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/api/admin/**")
      .hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
      .antMatchers("/api/programs")
      .permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/api/**")
      .authenticated()
      .anyRequest()
      .permitAll()
      .and()
      .logout()
      .permitAll()
      .and()
      .exceptionHandling()
      .authenticationEntryPoint(
        new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
      )
      .and()
      .oauth2Login()
      .failureHandler(new AuthFailureHandler())
      .tokenEndpoint()
      .accessTokenResponseClient(authorizationCodeTokenResponseClient());
  }

  private OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> authorizationCodeTokenResponseClient() {
    OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter converter = new OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setTokenResponseConverter(new AuthAccessTokenResponseConverter());

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(
      Arrays.asList(new FormHttpMessageConverter(), converter)
    );
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler());

    DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient responseClient = new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
    responseClient.setRestOperations(restTemplate);

    return responseClient;
  }

  private static class AuthFailureHandler
    implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(
      HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response,
      AuthenticationException exception
    )
      throws IOException, ServletException {
      Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
      response.setContentType("application/json");
      response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
      data.put("exception", exception.getMessage());
      response.getOutputStream().println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data));
    }
  }
}
```

`AuthAccessTokenResponseConverter.java`

```
public class AuthAccessTokenResponseConverter
        implements Converter<Map<String, String>, OAuth2AccessTokenResponse> {
    private static final Set<String> TOKEN_RESPONSE_PARAMETER_NAMES
            = Stream.of(OAuth2ParameterNames.ACCESS_TOKEN,
            OAuth2ParameterNames.TOKEN_TYPE,
            OAuth2ParameterNames.EXPIRES_IN,
            OAuth2ParameterNames.REFRESH_TOKEN,
            OAuth2ParameterNames.SCOPE)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    private OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType defaultAccessTokenType = OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType.BEARER;

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessTokenResponse convert(Map<String, String> tokenResponseParameters) {
        String accessToken = tokenResponseParameters.get(OAuth2ParameterNames.ACCESS_TOKEN);

        OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType accessTokenType = defaultAccessTokenType;
        if (OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType.BEARER
                .getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(tokenResponseParameters
                        .get(OAuth2ParameterNames.TOKEN_TYPE))) {
            accessTokenType = OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType.BEARER;
        }

        long expiresIn = 0;
        if (tokenResponseParameters.containsKey(OAuth2ParameterNames.EXPIRES_IN)) {
            expiresIn = Long.parseLong(tokenResponseParameters
                    .get(OAuth2ParameterNames.EXPIRES_IN));
        }

        Set<String> scopes = Collections.emptySet();
        if (tokenResponseParameters.containsKey(OAuth2ParameterNames.SCOPE)) {
            String scope = tokenResponseParameters.get(OAuth2ParameterNames.SCOPE);
            scopes = Arrays.stream(StringUtils.delimitedListToStringArray(scope, " "))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        }

        Map<String, Object> additionalParameters = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        tokenResponseParameters.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> !TOKEN_RESPONSE_PARAMETER_NAMES.contains(e.getKey()))
                .forEach(e -> additionalParameters.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));

        return OAuth2AccessTokenResponse.withToken(accessToken)
                .tokenType(accessTokenType)
                .expiresIn(expiresIn)
                .scopes(scopes)
                .additionalParameters(additionalParameters)
                .build();
    }

    public final void setDefaultAccessTokenType(OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType
                                                        defaultAccessTokenType) {
        Assert.notNull(defaultAccessTokenType, "defaultAccessTokenType cannot be null");
        this.defaultAccessTokenType = defaultAccessTokenType;
    }
}
```

`WebClientConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                               OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {
        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2 =
                new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrationRepository,
                        authorizedClientRepository);
        return WebClient.builder()
                .apply(oauth2.oauth2Configuration())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Full code here: https://github.com/piumal1999/scholarx